# how can I sort duplicate values in excel without repeated it sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, duplicate

i want the excel sort the values A to Z first then take the duplicate values to sort it again below A to Z like the following:

if i have the values **a,c,b,e,d,a,c** when i sort it a to z it's look like this = **a,a,b,c,c,d,e** but i want it look like this = **a,b,c,d,e,a,c**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper column for that, no macro required.

If your data is in column A and row 1 is used for labels, put this formula in cell B2 and copy down

=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)

Note the placement of the $ signs. Enter a column header in B1, for example "Count". Then click the Data ribbon > Sort. Create a sort by "Count" and add a second sort level to sort by "Data" (or whatever the label for column A is.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a non-standard functionality that you might have to implement yourself using [VBA macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx). However, this would require you to know how to program.